# Placing opening bracket on the next line but keeping collapes code in VS on the same line as function definition

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

In Visual Studio I use very often the collapsing functionality.

When I put opening bracket on the same line of my function definition >> the collapsed code is on the same line

[image]

[image]

When I put opening bracket on the next line of my function definition >> the collapsed code is on the next line

[image]

[image]

My question: is there any way for keeping the collapsed code on the same line of my function definition? Maybe a VS plugin?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? And what language? Just tried in C# in VS2013 and it's collapsing to a single line for me.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this problem occurs with TypeScript (VS2012).

Comment: I'll just leave this here : https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript an editor that is simpler to hack to your content.

Comment: You could try adjusting the formatting options in menu => Tools => Options => Text editor => C# => Formatting => New lines => Newline options for braces.

Comment: I already check the options but no one help.

Comment: In case you are using Resharper, you should look in Resharper Options -> Code Editing -> Typescript, as it overrides the VS configuration. Same may apply to other VS extensions.